# Regarding For loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

My task is to find the total in my prices list, this is what I wrote:

```
total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price
    print (f"Total = {total}")
```

The terminal gives out:

```
Total = 10
Total = 30
Total = 60
```

Whereas it is supposed to give me the final Total=60 instead of giving it in every line. How do I make it come only as total = 60? Please help

Comment: ``print (f"Total = {total}")`` is inside the ``for`` loop, so it runs on every iteration. Move it out of the ``for`` loop by dedenting it to run it only once, after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Print the total outside of the for loop. You are printing inside the for loop, that's why it is printing 3 times. I assume your prices list has 3 elements.

```
total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price

print (f"Total = {total}")
```

Comment: Thank you Sohan Bhai. Didn't expect a Bangladeshi to be active here but I am glad I found one :)

Comment: @brad_wade07 You are welcome. Good to have you here too. Keep practicing :)